# Haskell Record Field Dependency

Tags: haskell

```
data MyRecord = MyRecord {
  numberOfSides :: Int,
  shape :: Shape
}
```

`Shape` can be Triangle, Quadrilateral etc. depending on `numberOfSides`.

My question is: Those two fields are related. Is there a "trigger" mechanism to update the other when one field is updated? and if the two fields are in conflict then report a type error?

Another related scenario:

```
data MyRecord = MyRecord {
  players      :: [Player],
  numOfPlayers :: Int
}
```

I want to somehow automatically calculate `numberOfPlayers` based on the size of `players`.

PS: Is this somehow related to **GADT** and **dependant types**?

Comment: What do you mean by "when one field is updated" ? How do you envisage to update one field ?

Comment: Typically, you would just have a function `numberOfSides :: Shape -> Int` or `numberOfSides :: MyRecord -> Int` rather than storing it explicitly.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent, something like in OO, when obj.numberOfSides += 1, the other field could be programatically updated too in case I have to manually update all related fields.

Comment: But why is there a related field?  Why not just have a function that operates over the `Shape` or `[Player]` and returns the ground truth instead of some cached value?

Comment: @osager And in an OO language, you would have a method to update both values simultaneously, rather than expecting a simple assignment to `obj.shape` to change `obj.numberOfSides` as well. It's the same in Haskell: whatever function `updateShape :: Shape -> MyRecord -> MyRecord` you write would update both the `shape` and `numberOfSides` fields in the result.

Comment: @chepner I just find this error prone. Because quite a number of other 'variables' depend on one particular field and I could miss updating some of them. So I'm thinking whether we can leverage the type system, somehow.

Comment: If you miss updating them, it's a compile error. Haskell's type system is nice like that. Those sorts of things won't slip through the cracks like they might in another language.

Comment: Yes, it is error prone, which is why you write a function that creates `MyRecord` correctly rather than relying on record syntax like `some_value { shape=Rectangle}` to magically update `numberOfSides` for you. Whatever syntax you would write to link them would be just as verbose and error prone as writing a proper update function in the first place.

Comment: @chepner Suddently I realized why Haskell is called functional programming: You always create these little functions for your stuff.

Comment: If `MyRecord` is intended to be a black-box, like an object in OO, then you shouldn't be exporting its constructor and should be writing a function to do it anyway. This is akin to the factory pattern in OO, and should be used whenever you want to have "private" data in Haskell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Haskell, unlike in OO languages, you can't modify a field in place. So the usual approach, which is what I think you're thinking of, of having an explicit "setter" doesn't make sense in Haskell. The easiest thing, and this is well in line with the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) (which is very relevant in functional languages as well as OO languages), is to only store one of the fields and have the other be an accessor, as mentioned in a comment.

```
-- deriving (...) clauses and other boilerplate omitted for brevity

data Shape = Triangle | Quad | Pentagon | Other

data MyRecord = MyRecord Int

numSides :: Shape -> Int
numSides Triangle = 3
numSides Quad = 4
numSides Pentagon = 5
numSides Other = 0

shape :: Int -> Shape
shape 3 = Triangle
shape 4 = Quad
shape 5 = Pentagon
shape _ = Other

makeMyRecord :: Shape -> MyRecord
makeMyRecord = MyRecord . numSides

numberOfSides :: MyRecord -> Int
numberOfSides (MyRecord x) = x

shapeOf :: MyRecord -> Shape
shapeOf = shape . numberOfSides
```

Now, `Shape` can be `Enum` and `Bounded`, if you haven't done that already. From there, `shape` and `numSides` can be shortened in terms of the automatically generated `Enum` instance. If you want to be able to construct `MyRecord` from `Int`, you can either export the data constructor or define another `makeMyRecord'` to do it. And now, since we're using the DRY principle, you can just let users update the field freely and the other "field" will magically be updated.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is: Those two fields are related. Is there a "trigger" mechanism to update the other when one field is updated? and if the two fields are in conflict then report a type error?
>
> PS: Is this somehow related to GADT and dependant types?

This is related to dependent types, but not GADTs. Since this is Haskell, I would suggest simply storing the number of sides in the record and then writing a function `numTypes :: Int -> Shape`.